# how to protect an epub file from copying and printing?

Tags: epub, drm

I want to protect my epub files from invalid access.
Does anyone know how to protect an epub file from copying and printing?

Comment: Perhaps adding adobe drm protects your file from incompetent users. But it certainly will protect the epub from being bought by me.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.  And why the hell isn't this an official close reason I can't figure out.

Answer (score 4):

ePub files do not have a built-in method to do Digital Rights Management (DRM), which is what you're asking about. The specification does allow for various DRM schemes to be implemented on ePub files (see here -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPUB#Digital_rights_management) but there is no standardized, ePub-specific, way to do this. So, if you want to do this, check into the various types of DRM available out there for ePub.

One potential option might be [DocProtect 4](http://www.excelsoftware.com/news_docprotect_400.html).

Answer (score 3):

If you publish your ebook on Amazon, or Apple, you can choose to have them wrap it in their DRM, which essentially enforces rules about what devices it can be read on (for instance, up to N devices registered to the purchaser). It's not something you really want to do yourself. However, you should consider whether you really want to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you are need DRM (Digital Rights Management) solution. Which is expensive also, implementing is very hard. You have to choose your solution either way you need service like [www.editionguard.com](http://www.editionguard.com)